# Get value from a table through an ID from another table

Tags: php, sql

So basically I have a table : "task":

```
- id   -  morada -
-  1   -    1   -
```

And a "moradas" table:

```
-     ID     -      Morada     -   CodPostal
-      1     -    Street 1th   -     1523
```

I want through `task.Address` from the task table get the Address and Postal Code from the `moradas` table. Right now I'm only showing the int number of the address in the trip table.

```
<td><?php echo $fetch['address']?></td>
```

The query I have now is this

```
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE status != 'Done' ORDER BY `id` ASC");
```

How do I get the values from the Address table with that int and show them in that echo?

Comment: You should use JOIN, please provide the code you're using to query your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can user `INNER JOIN` for joining the two tables and get data from them.

`INNER JOIN` is used in this context assuming that each address id from database `Trip` corresponds to the actual address from database table: `address`.

```
SELECT T.Trip, A.Address, A.Postal_Code FROM Trip T
INNER JOIN address A ON T.Address = A.Address_ID
```

**Note:**

Your specified field names contain spaces.

I have added underscores instead of spaces in them.

Please put proper field names here.

[Reference:](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

**EDIT:**

Updated Query as per updated question:

```
SELECT T.id, A.Morada, A.CodPostal FROM task T
INNER JOIN moradas A ON T.morada = A.ID
```

Comment: See edits please. Forgot to mention my query and changed the names of the tables and columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When you put T.**** and A.****, shall I replace those with my table names? And how do I output the address to echo

Comment: You can use direct table names or you can use alias. You can loop over with `mysqli_*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Updated according to your tables and columns.
If you want `address` and `postal` code where your `task.id` and `moradas.id` value matches, then you should join two tables and get `address` and `postal code` from `moradas` table - 
Try this :-

```
$sql = "SELECT
  task.id,
  CONCAT(
    moradas.`Morada`,
    ' ',
    moradas.`CodPostal`
  ) AS address
FROM
  task
  LEFT JOIN moradas
    ON (task.id = moradas.id)
WHERE task.`status` != 'Done'
ORDER BY task.id ASC";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Address : " . $row["address"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results returned";
}
$conn->close();
```

I assume that `status` column is in your `task` table

This query will show your `address` and `postal` code as one column `address`. If you want those into saperate columns, you can skip concat and select `Morada` and `CodPostal` separately.

Comment: See edits please. Changed a few columns and showed my query.

Comment: What do I put in the echo? I have this <td><?php echo $fetch['address']?></td> and It gives me an undefined index error.

Comment: Updated answer. Take a look. If you have only one result then you can skip while loop but I think there should return as many rows as you have in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this scheme always as I will show you regarding your table names
If you have big data in MySQL like name. Postal code   Id. And suppose you have addresses in another table witch related to another tracking services as example

```
$ret = mysql_query("select t2.id, t2.name, t2.phone, t1.address From t2 Left join t1 on t2.id = t1.id where t2.id = $id ")
// $id = is variable you get from php request like $_GET and id table should have index in MySQL then do the following 
echo'<table>'
While ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ret) { 
echo"<td>" .$row["addresse"]."<td>";
// repeat this for all retrieved data 
}
echo '</table>'
```

Now you will have table in php output with all data in the query.

- If query returns one record so table will have one result
- If query have 10000 records as result so table will have 10000

You may put limit in query to retrieve 100 result per request

Comment: Why are you writing this with the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library, and using it, even for a demonstration like this, is 2019 is just setting a bad example. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Far better to give a modern example using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Right that library is depricated and there's many notifications about this on php.net . I just use it as reference. mysqli is good as you said . for me I don't use both of them long time. I mainly use PDO since I usually rotate queries on many servers .